# AssertionError: You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def tweet_create_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {
            "request" : request
        }
    serializer = TweetSerializer(data=request.POST, context=context)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return JsonResponse({}, status=201)
```

I am not trying to access the data but the error is thrown.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was in the debugging mode - the debugger was accessing the serializer data SOMEHOW (i don't know), therefore the exception was thrown - this is from a stack overflow post that I forgot to save. Also, I switched from vs code to PyCharm because I got my hands dirty with different extensions and I think it overcomplicates the whole development process(in my opinion) - for example, errors are all white-colored. I tried to use ZSH shell and other stuff to change the design but it just was a waste of time that generates more and more problems and this made me switch to PyCharm where everything is easier. Also, the debugger in PyCharm was not throwing any errors to the same project. I cannot share the stack trace because I don't know what has changed in the vs code overnight but it started to work :)). Maybe some magic.